# Why Stripe testMode working but liveMode not?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe PHP on my website. When I test that on testMode it's worked properly. But, When I tried to use liveMode it's not working.

Note: SSL not used on my website

Does SSL is a cause to not working liveMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe will only work over HTTPS in live mode: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#tls